# What characters are usable in a variable name in ObjectScript on a "Unicode" installation?

Tags: java, intersystems-cache, objectscript

I have a parser (in Java) for ObjectScript which works quite well, except for one thing: I don't parse "Unicode variable names".

The problem is that the documentation is not very explanative on this subject; and what is more, it misdefines Unicode as "16 bits". This tells me that only characters within the BMP are allowed.

But which ones? The number of Unicode blocks defined in the JDK [is frighteningly high](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html), and scripts [aren't any better](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeScript.html).

I could maybe use [`Character.isLetter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter-char-) (note, I elected the version with a char, not an int), but I'm sure that even that would be too large...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eduard was pretty much correct, i.e. local variable could be starting from percent or "alphabetic" character, followed by "alphabetic" characters or digits.

```
[\p{Alphabetic}%][\p{Alphabetic}\d]*
```

The most important to note here - what is the "alphabetic"? This implies latin letter or alphabetic in current Caché locale. I.e. with Russian/Unicode locale installed you could write something like:

```
set порусски = 1
```

or within Japanese locale:

```
USER>set a=$c(12354)

USER>set @a=88

USER>write

a="あ"
あ=88
```

Comment: Owch. So does this mean that code programmed in a certain country, using characters available in that country only, will not even compile on a Caché installation meant for another country??

Comment: Might be, depending on locale settings. Sorry for that! [Though Japanese name as above was ok in Russian/Unicode locale]
That's why we prohibit using of Russian names in global, local or types names, in our local [COS Guidelines](https://github.com/intersystems-ru/cos-guidelines#mandatory-part).

Comment: in any case, wherever you write parser for highlighting or validation, you should nt try to be exactly precise. Usually, more practical approach would be to just allow "good enough" superset of syntax what actual compiler would accept. So, in this case generic Unicode alphabetic property would be good enough approximation of real life complexities in Unicode Cache' NLS locales.

Comment: Note that `\p{Alphabetic}`, from what I understand, can _also_ match code points outside the BMP from what I understand; and according to [rfg's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35452818/1093528), those are invalid!

Answer (score 2):

See docs [here](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCOS_variables) and [here](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GORIENT_appx_identifiers). To sum up:

A local variable name must be a valid identifier. Its first character must be either a letter or the percent (%) character. Variable names starting with the “%” character are known as “percent variables” and have different scoping rules.

Comment: I know these docs. What isn't clear is whether code points outside the BMP are valid at all.